# If $A, B$ are equal-sized sets that partition $V(C_{2n})$, then the multisets of distances of vertices within $A$ and $B$, respectively, are equal.

Tags: graph-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint subsets of $V(C_{2n})$ such that $|A| = |B| =
> n$. Prove that the multiset of $\binom{n}{2}$ distances between vertices of $A$ is equal to the multiset of $\binom{n}{2}$ distances between the vertices of $B$.

There is a slick proof I was introduced to that uses the distance graph for a fixed distance. However, I came up with a proof of my own that I am struggling to finish.

**Motivation:** I created some examples of $C_8$ with vertices colored red or white depending on if they are in $A$ or $B$. No matter what example I try, I can find a line dividing the vertices in half such that the reflection of any vertex across this line yields a different colored vertex.

[image: Examples of C_8 with lines]

Putting this into more rigorous terms, label the vertices of $C_{2n}$ with $0,1,...,2n-1$ such that $ij \in E(C_{2n})$ if and only if $i-j \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 2n$. **For simplicity, assume all arithmetic is done modulo $2n$.** These reflections are in the form $i \mapsto m-i$ for some integer $m$ and are completely determined by where they send $0$. Note that $0$ cannot be sent to an even vertex $2k$; otherwise, the vertex $k$ is mapped to itself and the reflection doesn't map vertices to different colored vertices. Thus, $0 \mapsto 2k-1$ for some integer $1 \le k \le n$. Furthermore, the reflections are in the form $i \mapsto 2k-1-i$ for some integer $1 \le k \le n$.

*Claim.* There exists an integer $1 \le k \le n$ such that $B = \{2k-1-i : i \in A\}$. In particular, the map $\sigma:A \to B$ given by $i \mapsto 2k-1-i$ is a well-defined bijection.

***How do I prove this claim?***

Assuming the claim holds, the rest of the proof follows quite nicely. Observe that for any $i,j \in A$, we have $\text{dist}(i,j) = \min\{i-j,2n-i+j\}$ (still modulo $2n$) and
\begin{align*}
\text{dist}(\sigma(i),\sigma(j)) &= \text{dist}(2k-1-i,2k-1-j) \\
&= \min\{(2k-1-i)-(2k-1-j),2n-(2k-1-i)+(2k-1-j)\} \\
&= \min\{-i+j,2n+i-j\} \\
&= \min\{2n-i+j,i-j\} \\
&= \text{dist}(i,j).
\end{align*}
Therefore, the bijection $\sigma:A \to B$ preserves distances between pairs of vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your claim is incorrect. Here's a counterexample. Let $n=6$ and $A=\{0,2,3,6,7,8\}$. It is easy to check that for any reflection $f$ of the cycle $C_{12}$ we have $f(A)\cap A\neq\emptyset$

Comment: Indeed, I double-checked it and this is a counterexample. What a shame. Thanks!